# FB.getLoginStatus not working with https

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I know this is a damn simple question but I haven't found any solution for this. When my app is being opened by a person having secure browsing on `https://` then `FB.getLoginStatus` doesn't trigger. First I used `FB._HTTPS` and it was working now FB has removed all elements having `._`. So how to make `FB.getLoginStatus` working with `https://`? My code looks like

```
 <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
 <script>
        console.log("layout");
        //FB._https = (window.location.protocol == "https:");
        //FB._https = true;
        console.log("fb https true");
        FB.init({
            appId : '<?php echo $this->appId; ?>',
            channelUrl : '//<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; ?>/static/content/channel.php',
            status : true, // check login status
            cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml : true // parse XFBML
        });
   </script>
 function PostAction(custom_action)
 {
     console.log('outside of fbgetlogin');
     FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)
    {
        console.log("in getlogin status");
        if (response.authResponse) {
            fbcallBack(response);
        } else {
            FB.login(fbcallBack, {scope:'publish_stream'});
        }
    });
}
```

My channel.php file contains

```
  <?php
 $cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
 header("Pragma: public");
 header("Cache-Control: max-age=".$cache_expire);
 header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire) . ' GMT');
 ?>
   <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

My `PostAction` function is triggered at `onclick` event. FB.getLoginStatus`is triggered when user is on`http://`bit not triggered when user is on`https://`

Can any body tell me how to make getloginstatus work with https://?

**Update Problem in Detail**

Let me tell you the problem in detail. I have implemented Action verbs of facebook. I have implemented three verbs. Want, Has and recommend. Now I want to check the login status of the user when user clicks on that button. So as you see the I have called PostAction() function at onclick event on my custom button. Now at that event I want to check whether user is logged in or not. This function exists in a different file. And init function exists in may layout file (for generalization point of view). Now how can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use asynchronous loading and call getLoginStatus from with in.

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
    appId  : '135669679827333',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    channelUrl : 'https://anotherfeed.com/emo/channel.html', // channel.html file
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
        }); 
  //      
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
//          
        });
      };
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: hi Shawn. actually my init function and get login status are 2 different files. My layout.php file contains init function and get loging status function in an other file. how can I put these together?

Comment: :-| i put all of my init, GLS functions in my index.php just below the body, i get best results this way. I think i would need to see a full layout of your pages to help you with that.

Comment: Let me tell you the problem in detail. I have implemented Action verbs of facebook. I have implemented three verbs. Want, Has and recommend. Now I want to check the login status of the user when user clicks on that button. So as you see the I have called PostAction() function at onclick event on my custom button. Now at that event I want to check whether user is logged in or not. This function exists in a different file. And init function exists in may layout file (for generalization point of view). Now how can I handle this situation?